# XQuery : Fastest way to check dates

Tags: xml, date, xquery, exist-db

According to the fact I have this XML file :

```
<entries>
  <entry date="2012-10-09T12:09:09">...</entry>
  <entry date="2012-10-09T14:19:23">...</entry>
  ...
  <entry date="2012-10-13T00:00:00">...</entry>
</entries>
```

And `$dateBegin := '2012-10-09T13:00:00'` and `$dateEnd := '2012-10-12T00:00:00'`. I'm looking for an efficient way of getting the entries ranged between $dateBegin and $dateEnd, any idea?

Comment: Are the entries in the XML document sorted by the dates?

Comment: Which query processor are you using? Performance tends to depend heavily on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the confirmed by Rob (the OP) fact, that the `entry` elements appear sorted in the XML document, this might be faster**:

```
for $dateBegin in xs:dateTime('2012-10-09T13:00:00'),
    $dateEnd in xs:dateTime('2012-10-12T00:00:00')
    return
            /*/*[xs:dateTime(@date) ge $dateBegin
               and
                . << /*/*[xs:dateTime(@date) gt $dateEnd][1]
                ]
```

**When this XQuery is evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<entries>
  <entry date="2012-10-09T12:09:09">...</entry>
  <entry date="2012-10-09T14:19:23">...</entry>
  ...
  <entry date="2012-10-13T00:00:00">...</entry>
</entries>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<entry date="2012-10-09T14:19:23">...</entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately it still takes a very long time to proceed, my XML file containing almost 90000 entries.

Comment: @Rob, If the start date is at the start of the document and the end date is at  the end of the document, nothing can help. The same in case when both dates are at the very end of the document. If the dates are close to the start, then this should operate fast. Also, if it is guaranteed that the start and end date are equal to dates in the document, one can use XSLT and keys -- to find the start entry and the end entry -- this is O(1). If it is guaranteed that the sequence access by position is O(1) (such as in Saxon), one can write a binary search to locate the starting and ending `entry`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so finally I realized that `let $entries := //entry[(xs:dateTime(./@date/string()) ge $dateBegin) and (xs:dateTime(./@date/string()) le $dateEnd)]` works. Still wondering if a better solution exists though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a range-index on the entry/@date attribute defined for the collection? If not i believe that would speed up the query.